# Как правильно передать значение в тест?

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit, test-automation

Работаю с mvp паттерном и хочу протестировать в презентере метод из 2-х строчек

Вот такой метод

```
final public void setOriginPreviewImage() {
    final String path = model.getImageFilePath();
    iActivityAcceptNotAccept.setPreviewImage(path);
}
```

Метод получает путь и передает его через интерфейс во вью.

Вот написал локальный тест

```
public class PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest {

private PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept presenter;

@Mock ModelAcceptNotAccept model;
@Mock IActivityAcceptNotAccept iActivityAcceptNotAccept;

@Before public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    presenter = new PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept(iActivityAcceptNotAccept);
}

@Test public void setOriginPreviewImage() throws Exception {
    presenter.setOriginPreviewImage();
    when(model.getImageFilePath()).thenReturn("path");
    String path = model.getImageFilePath();
    verify(iActivityAcceptNotAccept).setPreviewImage(path);
}
```

В этом методе я в первой строке запускаю выполнение самого метода, потом в `when()` указываю что если будет вызван метод `getImageFilePath()` то верни значение `"path"` и в третей строке я собственно и вызываю метод `getImageFilePath()` и ожидаю что мне вернется значение которое я установил для этого теста `"path"` , но я получаю вот такую ошибку

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.cameraTools.ImageSaver.getImageFilePath(ImageSaver.java:37)
>       at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.model.ModelAcceptNotAccept.getImageFilePath(ModelAcceptNotAccept.java:14)

и получаю ее при выполнении метода `model.getImageFilePath();`...

Тест не возвращает мне значение которое я установил тут

```
when(model.getImageFilePath()).thenReturn("path");
```

а идет в функцию и пытается достать путь которого там нет, так как это тест...

Что сделал не так?

**ПРАВКА**

Модель попадает в презентер вот так

```
public final class PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept implements IPresenterAcceptNotAccept {
private IActivityAcceptNotAccept iActivityAcceptNotAccept;
private ModelAcceptNotAccept model;

public PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept(IActivityAcceptNotAccept iActivityAcceptNotAccept) {
    this.iActivityAcceptNotAccept = iActivityAcceptNotAccept;
    this.model = new ModelAcceptNotAccept(this);
}
```

**ПРАВКА**

Код модели

```
public class ModelAcceptNotAccept {
private IPresenterAcceptNotAccept iPresenterAcceptNotAccept;

public ModelAcceptNotAccept(IPresenterAcceptNotAccept iPresenterAcceptNotAccept) {
    this.iPresenterAcceptNotAccept = iPresenterAcceptNotAccept;
}

public String getImageFilePath(){
    return ImageSaver.getImageFilePath();
}

}
```

Comment: как модель попадает в презентер?

Comment: И ещё, сначала надо мокать, а потом вызывать метод презентера

Comment: @temq добавил в вопрос как модель попадает в презентер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге вот так все заработало

```
public class PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest {

private PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept presenter;

@Mock private ContractAcceptNotAccept.View contractAcceptNotAccept;

@Mock private ContractModelAcceptNotAccept model;

@Before public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    presenter = new PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept(contractAcceptNotAccept, model);
}

@Test public void setOriginPreviewImage() throws Exception {
    doReturn("path").when(model).getImageFilePath();
    presenter.setOriginPreviewImage();
    String path = model.getImageFilePath();
    verify(contractAcceptNotAccept).setPreviewImage(path);
}
```

Вот что я изменил

1. Нужно писать не так

   ```
   when(model.getImageFilePath()).thenReturn("path");
   ```

   а так

   ```
   doReturn("path").when(model).getImageFilePath();
   ```

   Только я еще не разобрался в чем разница, так что если кто может обьяснить, то спасибо)
2. И второе , строка

   ```
   doReturn("path").when(model).getImageFilePath();
   ```

   должна быть первая в тестовом методе.

Answer (score 0):

У вас метод final. Mockito не работает с final и static. Для это нужно использовать PowerMock

Comment: мок делается не на финальный метод, а на метод модели, а тестируется как раз финальный мето, но это не имеет никакого значения

Comment: Да, я что-то просмотрел. Надо бы код модели посмотреть

Comment: добавил код модели